# Rmarkdown: Output loop 200 consecutive dead cycles

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm having trouble creating a PDF using `rmarkdown`. Because when I knit to pdf there was an error saying.

[image]

I have researched on this and most people say that I use `\maxdeadcycles=200`. But it does not work for me.

Comment: Please try to simplify your code to a [mcve] that you can post in addition to the error message, which should be text, not an image, to make it possible to find your question with a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this has been already resolved. I just changed the \maxdeadcycles from 200 to 300.